# run bash commande by ssh using Java

Tags: java, bash, command-line, ssh

I want to run a script with ssh from java. The script takes a number as parameter. I launch this code :

```
String myKey="/home/my_key.pem";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

String commande = "ssh -i "
+myKey+" ubuntu@ec2-56-75-88-183.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com './runScript.bash 8000'";
Process p = runtime.exec(commande);      

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {

System.out.println(line);
line = reader.readLine();
}

p.waitFor();
```

I obtain this error :

```
bash: ./runScript.bash 8000: No such file or directory
```

The name of file is correct. `chmod` given to runScript.bash is `777`.

When i run the command line directly from bash it works. But from IDE, it does not.

How can i do to run this commande line correctly please ?

Comment: I'd suggest using a native Java SSH library -- there are several -- rather than trying to go through the command-line tooling.

Comment: In particular, I've had good experiences with JSch: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: Here you have a simple example using JSch : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24279641/3315914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error makes it clear:

```
bash: ./runScript.bash 8000: No such file or directory
```

This indicates that the shell is trying to invoke a script called `./runScript.bash 8000` -- with the space and the 8000 in the filename of the script.

It's rare for me to be telling anyone to use fewer quotes, but, well, this is actually a case where that would fix things.

Better would be to avoid double evaluation altogether:

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] {
   "ssh",
   "-i", myKey,
   "ubuntu@ec2-56-75-88-183.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
   "./runScript 8000"
})
```

Comment: This happens to work due to the special semantics of `ssh` which doesn't care that Java mangles your arguments. You should never use `Runtime.exec(String)`. Use `Runtime.exec(String[])` instead.

Comment: @thatotherguy, I feel lazy now for not pointing that out. Amended appropriately.