# Problems executing Bash command over SSH from Java

Tags: java, bash, ssh

I am having trouble executing commands on a remote GNU/Linux system over SSH from Java. The following commands work fine when executed in the local Bash (of course the user and host are different but the behaviour is unchanged).

```
$ ssh user@host.example.com 'hostname'
host
$ ssh user@host.example.com 'hostname -f'
host.example.com
$ ssh user@host.example.com "hostname -f"
host.example.com
```

Doing what I think is the same from Java fails for anything more complex than `hostname` without arguments.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.Executor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (String argument : new String[]{"hostname", "'hostname'", "\"hostname\"",
            "'hostname -f'", "\"hostname -f\""}) {
            CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("ssh");
            commandLine.addArgument("user@host.example.com");
            commandLine.addArgument(argument);
            System.out.println(commandLine);

            final Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

            try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(os, err));
                int exitcode = executor.execute(commandLine);
                System.out.println("exitcode=" + exitcode);
                System.out.println(new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));
                System.err.println(new String(err.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
ssh user@host.example.com hostname
exitcode=0

host

ssh user@host.example.com 'hostname'
exitcode=0

host

ssh user@host.example.com "hostname"
exitcode=0
host


ssh user@host.example.com 'hostname -f'
Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
ssh user@host.example.com "hostname -f"
Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
```

As you can see, executing `hostname -f` over SSH from Java fails with an exit code of 127. I wonder *what* bash (local or remote) was unable to find *what* command.

I've tried to use the variant

```
addArgument(String argument, boolean handleQuoting)
```

but there was no difference in the result.

How must I build a `CommandLine` from Java that works over SSH?

Comment: try using jsch (com.jcraft.jsch.JSch) - it is purpose built for ssh

Comment: I've tried JSch in a different approach but failed to configure publickey authentication. Any hint about that?

Comment: sorry I have only used it with username/passwd as in  `JSch shell = new JSch();
          session = shell.getSession(userName, serverIP, 22);  
          session.setPassword(password);`

Comment: @LutzHorn I've a working example of JSch, with pubkey authentication. Would be an answer to this question?

Comment: @rpax If it uses `exec` to execute a single remote command and then closes the connection, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @LutzHorn Ok. Digging into my code snippets folder...

Comment: @LutzHorn Done. Was what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSch with publickey authentication.

If you only want to use `exec` to execute a single remote command and then closes the connection, here you have a working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String user = "--";
        String host = "--";

        try
        {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            // key authentication
            jsch.addIdentity("id_rsa");
            // open a new session on port 22
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

            session.connect();
            String command = "ls /";
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

            channel.setInputStream(null);

            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                while (in.available() > 0)
                {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    sb.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed())
                {
                    if (in.available() > 0)
                        continue;
                    System.out.println("exit-status: "
                            + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                }
            }
            //disconnecting and closing
            channel.disconnect();

            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Output: ");
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             //something should be done here
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Output:

```
exit-status: 0
Output: 
1
bin
boot
cgroup
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
lost+found
....
```

Hope it helps

Note: `id_rsa` is the path to the key file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer regarding Jsch. I've tried a different approach which writes the command to a temporary file and then executes it locally.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.Executor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String command = "ssh user@host 'hostname -f'";
        int exitCode = executeCommand(command);
    }

    private static int executeCommand(final String command) {
        int exitcode = -1;
        File temp = null;
        try {
            temp = File.createTempFile("foo", ".tmp");
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(temp);) {
                IOUtils.write(command, os);
            } finally {
                // os is closed
            }

            CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("bash");
            commandLine.addArgument(temp.getAbsolutePath());

            final Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(os, err));
                exitcode = executor.execute(commandLine);
                System.out.println("exitcode=" + exitcode);
                System.out.println(new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));
                System.err.println(new String(err.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));
            } finally {
                // os and err are closed
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage);
        } finally {
            if (temp != null) {
                temp.delete();
            }
        }
        return exitcode;
    }
}
```